# Serial port handler error when perl thread exit

Tags: multithreading, perl, asynchronous, serial-port

I'm using threads in perl (5.12 ActiveState) to allow parallel and asyncronous writing on two different COM ports on Windows. This is how my code looks like:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use warnings;
use strict;
use Win32::SerialPort;
use threads;

my $ComPortObj = new Win32::SerialPort ("COM10") or die ("This is the bitter end...");
[... omit port settings ...]

my $ComPortObj2 = new Win32::SerialPort ("COM6") or die ("This is the bitter end...");
[... omit port settings ...]    

my $s_read = "";

my $HangupThr = async 
{
    # printf("THREAD - Wait 3 seconds\n");
    # sleep(3);
    print("THREAD - write on COM10: AT\n");
    $ComPortObj->write("AT\r") || die ("Unable to send command\n");
    printf("THREAD - Wait 1 second\n");
    sleep(1);
    $s_read = $ComPortObj2->input;
    # $s_read =~ s/\n/N/g;
    # $s_read =~ s/\r/R/g;
    print("THREAD - read from COM6: $s_read\n");
    return 1;

};
$HangupThr->detach();

# printf("MAIN - Wait 4 seconds\n");
# sleep(4);
print("MAIN - write on COM6: AT\n");
$ComPortObj2->write("AT\r") || die ("Unable to send command\n");
printf("MAIN - Wait 1 second\n");
sleep(1);
$s_read = $ComPortObj->input;
# $s_read =~ s/\n/N/g;
# $s_read =~ s/\r/R/g;
print("MAIN - read from COM10: $s_read\n");

$ComPortObj->close();
$ComPortObj2->close();
```

What I get is an error when program exits. Complete output:

```
MAIN - write on COM6: AT
THREAD - write on COM10: AT
MAIN - Wait 1 second
THREAD - Wait 1 second
MAIN - read from COM10: AT
OK

THREAD - read from COM6: AT
OK

Error in PurgeComm at C:\userdata\Perl scripts\src\handler_error.pl line 0 thread 1
The operation completed successfully.
Error in GetCommTimeouts at C:\userdata\Perl scripts\src\handler_error.pl line 0 thread 1
Error Closing handle 184 for \\.\COM6
The handle is invalid.
Error closing Read Event handle 188 for \\.\COM6
The handle is invalid.
Error closing Write Event handle 192 for \\.\COM6
The handle is invalid.
Error in PurgeComm at C:\userdata\Perl scripts\src\handler_error.pl line 0 thread 1
The handle is invalid.
Error in GetCommTimeouts at C:\userdata\Perl scripts\src\handler_error.pl line 0 thread 1
Error Closing handle 144 for \\.\COM10
The handle is invalid.
Error closing Read Event handle 148 for \\.\COM10
The handle is invalid.
Error closing Write Event handle 180 for \\.\COM10
The handle is invalid.
```

This is related to serial port handlers purge, which I have no idea on how perl duplicates in threads. I've tried various close attempts in thread, main... without success. Furthermore I have to use the same ports both in main program and thread. Any suggestion to prevent these errors?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You are dealing with Serial Ports and at any point only one process can have control on the serial ports(some terminal switches provide multiple login but thats not your case) In windows  when one Process connects to COM it automatically disconnects other process. You can try this by trying to login to same COM port twice from the windows machine and the other port should disconnect which should lead to invalid handles you are seeing as error.

Other things you can try

1. Create Com Object **Inside** the thread, Use it and Destroy the object before accessing it on other thread

Comment: I made some experiments and the only way to avoid the error is close all com objects in main program BEFORE starting the thread. In fact the error is related to the duplicated com object that is made when thread is started. Please check the comment to @pilcrow below for further details. And yes, once I've no duplicates I than have to correctly open and close com objects inside the thread.